# How to save images in a subfolder just created in c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a subFolder with code and want to save images in that folder

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile && photot == true || FileUpload2.HasFile && photot == true || FileUpload3.HasFile && photot == true || FileUpload4.HasFile && photot == true)
    {
        string filePath = Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/"));
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileNameSecond = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileNameThird = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileNameForth = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload4.PostedFile.FileName);
        string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/");
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/" + fileName));
        FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/" + fileNameSecond));
        FileUpload3.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/" + fileNameThird));
        FileUpload4.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/" + fileNameForth));
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    {
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Specify a "currently active folder"

     myImagePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/"));
    //Create a new subfolder under the current active folder
    newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(myImagePath,txtFolder.Text );

    // Create the subfolder
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
}
```

How can I save Images in the new subfolder just created with code??

Comment: You haven't actually tried anything. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using ASP.NET WebForms to upload create folder then start uploading images to it.
I advice you to show a tree for users to choose from, then send the folder path with each post.
If you have to do it like you're doing now, then maybe this will help:
- Use ViewState, to save created path.
- With each button click you should have the value you saved and you need to use it to upload the images to:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /// your code for creating folder goes here...then
   ViewState["CreatedPath"] = newPath;
}
```

In button 1:

```
protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   /// your code before FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs line goes here...
   /// then use ViewState["CreatedPath"] to get the value you previously saved.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly created folder is stored in the `newPath` variable, but you're not using it.
You'll have to replace

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/");
```

with

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath(newPath);
```

and - since `folderPath` is currently not used as well - change all FileUpload operations from

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images_Clients/" + fileName));
```

to

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(folderPath+ fileName));
```

All this assumes that `newPath` is an instance or class variable which is accessible in `Button1_Click2`